# Can your NPC mages become Blood Mages if you are not a mage? (Spoiler)

Tags: dragon-age-origins

As I understand, the only way to unlock the Blood Mage specialization is to personally enter the Fade during [Arl of Redliffe](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Arl_of_Redcliffe), something that can only be done if you are a mage Warden. However, I've seen a few old guides that list either Wynne or Morrigan as Blood Mages despite not playing as a mage.

So my question is as the title says. Is it possible for Wynne or Morrigan to become Blood Mages if I myself am not a mage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and no. You will not be able to unlock the specialization on that character, but the specializations are actually designed to unlock across playthroughs, so if you get the Blood Mage specialization on one Mage-class character, you can then use it on any further mages - either the Player Character, Morrigan, or Wynne - on any other playthroughs.

Comment: Ah, just like the achievements and bonus skills in Mass Effect then.